# Guzzle passing multiple dimension array

Tags: php, guzzle

My cURL request looks like:

```
http://httpbin.org/post -d '{"multifilter":{"limit":5}}'
```

My Guzzle code:

```
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post');
$postBody = $request->getBody();
$postBody->setField('multifilter', array("limit"=>"5"));
$response = $client->send($request);
```

This line

```
$postBody->setField('multifilter', array("limit"=>"5"));
```

is not correct, but how to set variable as array ?

Or maybe exist something to add json query ? I mean something like `addJsonquery('multifilter":{"limit":5}}')` ?

Comment: Have you tried ('multifilter[limit]', 5) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is add json to `body`

```
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', $url, [
        'body' => $json,
]);
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Answer in github:

github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1027

Comment: Since you asked the same question in the github repo others might be interested in that one, too: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1027